# :hover срабатывает при схлопнутом предке

Tags: css

Приветствую! не совсем понимаю логику срабатывания :hover у схлопнутого родителя (когда все элементы внутри `float:left`).
Подскажите, почему возникает такой эффект? Пример тут, и на jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tayhatsu/a8k5jq4p/

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: .5;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 20px;
}

.child:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а что значит  `display:float;` ?

Comment: ошибся, имелось в виду `float: left` или `float:right`

Comment: аа ! а я уж подумал что что то поменялось в спецификации w3.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.
Все очень даже логично - родитель .parent хоть и схлопнутый, но он все-же есть. Когда вы наводите на дочерний элемент (не важно схлопнут при этом родитель или нет), то применяются стили к родителю: .parent:hover и соответственно стили к .child:hover.

При этом, если навести курсор между блоками, то :hover не сработает. Так происходит потому, что у родителя - .parent с дочерними элементами с заданным float'ом высота = 0 и соответственно курсор на него не попадает, а попадает лишь при наведении на дочерние элементы.

Немного сумбурно получилось, но надеюсь, что понятно объяснил))